# Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint (foreign keys)

Tags: mysql, database

```
CREATE DATABASE my_db;

CREATE TABLE class (
  classID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nameClass varchar(255),
  classLeader varchar(255),
  FOREIGN KEY (classLeader) REFERENCES student(studentID),
  PRIMARY KEY (classID));

CREATE TABLE student (
  studentID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  lastName varchar(255),
  firstName varchar(255),
  classID int,
  FOREIGN KEY (classID) REFERENCES class(classID),
  PRIMARY KEY (studentID));
```

I am trying to ensure data consistency between the tables by using foreign key so that the DBMS can check for errors; however, it seems we can't do that for some reason. What's the error and is there an alternative? Also, when I fill a table that has a foreign key, I can't fill the field that's reserved for the foreign key(s), right? Also, is a foreign key considered to be a key at all?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The most likely issue is this line:

```
FOREIGN KEY (classLeader) REFERENCES student(studentID),
```

The datatype of classLeader is VARCHAR(255). That has to **match the datatype** of the referenced column... `student.studentID`. And of course, the `student` table has to exist, and the `studentID` column has to exist, and the `studentID` column should be the PRIMARY KEY of the student table (although I believe MySQL allows this to be a UNIQUE KEY, rather than a PRIMARY KEY, or even just have an index on it.)

In any case, what's missing here is the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE student;`

---

There's a datatype mismatch.

The `classLeader VARCHAR(255)` column cannot be a foreign key reference to `studentID INT`.

The datatypes of the two columns has to match.

Comment: CREATE DATABASE my_db3;

CREATE TABLE class (classID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nameClass varchar(255),
classLeader int,
FOREIGN KEY (classLeader) REFERENCES student(studentID),
PRIMARY KEY (classID));

SHOW CREATE TABLE student (studentID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
lastName varchar(255),
firstName varchar(255),
classID int,
FOREIGN KEY (classID) REFERENCES class(classID),
PRIMARY KEY (studentID));

Comment: @GEORGEReed..It would be useful if you can post error you are getting.

Comment: 07:25:05 CREATE TABLE class (classID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, nameClass varchar(255), classLeader int, FOREIGN KEY (classLeader) REFERENCES student(studentID), PRIMARY KEY (classID)) Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint 0.094 sec

Comment: Thanks a lot. In my case the difference was just that on Table A the field was Int(10) UNSIGNED and on Table B it was Int(10). That's enough for a type mismatch! :o

Comment: @Ricardo Appleton: yes, that's a mismatch. I should have emphasized that the datatypes of the two columns has to match **EXACTLY**.

Answer (score 9):

You are getting this error because of in `FOREIGN KEY (classLeader) REFERENCES student(studentID)`
datatype of `studentID` and `classLeader` is different.Datatype of primary key column and foreign key column must be same.

[From MySQL Site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar data types. 
>   The size and sign of integer types must be the same. 
>   The length of string types need not be the same. 
>   For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation must > be the same.

Comment: +1 This answers the question; this answer identifies the problem causing the error.

Comment: I would add that columns using unsigned property can also cause this error. Both columns must have the same definition of signed or unsigned.

Answer (score 5):

Though it is a late answer, I hope it would help few people.

I faced the same issue. But, here the Data types were also same.

But, When I checked the create table statement, I found that One table created using a engine called "MyISAM" and another one was using "InnoDB".

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE <TABLE NAME>
```

Then I changed both tables engine to "InnoDB" and it worked(I was able create Foreign Key)

Answer (score 0):

The error gets resolved:

To create a Foreign key for a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE USERS_SO (
    USERNAME VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    ENABLED SMALLINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (USERNAME)
);
```

The below code works fine

```
CREATE TABLE AUTHORITIES_SO (
    USERNAME VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    AUTHORITY VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (USERNAME) REFERENCES USERS_SO(USERNAME)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a header and footer in sql dump otherwise you will see all sort of errors when restoring database

Header should look something like below -:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

and footer should look something like below -:

```
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Hope the above helps

Cheers
S

Answer (score 0):

Along with all the properties mentioned in the other answers, the CHARSET of both tables too should match for successful mapping the foreign keys between them.

Answer (score 0):

just set attributes to UNSIGNED for classID

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to the question but related to title of the question (`Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint`) -
If anyone faces this problem (with correct syntax), make sure there are no generated columns that are using the foreign key column - for me, it took quite a while to figure out it was because of following:

> A foreign key constraint on the base column of a stored generated
> column cannot use CASCADE, SET NULL, or SET DEFAULT as ON UPDATE or ON
> DELETE referential actions.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

I was using a generated column and using one of these CASCADE options on foreign key constraint

Answer (score 0):

check the column charset and the cloumn collate, They should be the same in both tables, that is how I fixed mine.

Answer (score -1):

Set end reference point of the key to 'Unique'

Answer (score -1):

**Make sure if yourtable is using InnoDB engine**

First, verify if engine is INNODB or not:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtable
```

If not change the engine to InnoDB:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Answer (score -2):

Remove the `Engine, CHARSET, COLLATE` from Query , then checkout . It works for me.