# WordPress users table - getting error while adding foreign key

Tags: mysql, wordpress

imagine i want to save more information about each user in `wordpress` . i create a table named `users_information`, so i should create a `user_id` column which is a foreign key for `Wordpress` `wp_users` table .

but in `phpmyadmin` tool when I want to create this relation, I get this error:

```
MySQL said:
#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

I have tried many different ways but still I'm stuck.
you should also know that user_id is index and . my problem is wordpress.
please help me.
how can I fix this ?

Comment: `SHOW WARNINGS;` i guess you have missed the index on the column

Comment: See previous SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29248057/cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-mysql-error-1215-hy000 . Answer of this question will help

Comment: i didnt miss index... its index... i have done relations before. i think the problem is wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you're using InnoDb as table format