# Error : Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-5.6

## Problem

I have two tables. The first one is populated; the second one is empty.

I want the second one to have a foreign key which references a column in the first one.

My understanding is that it should be possible as long as:

- Both tables have the same **Engine**
- Both columns have the same **Datatype**
- Both columns have the same **Length**
- Both columns have the same **Collation**
- Both columns have the same **Character Set**
- The parent column has a **Unique** key
- The parent column has a matching value for every value in the child column

In my case, all of these conditions are true, but MySQL still will not allow a foreign key relationship.

What other condition(s) need to be met?

## Example

*Note: This example gives a general idea of the situation, but it will not reproduce the error.*

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `parents` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4

CREATE TABLE `kids` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

`parents` is populated. `kids` is empty.

`kids.parent_id` cannot become a foreign key of `parents.id`:

```
ALTER TABLE `kids` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `parents` (`id`);
-- Error : Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

## Failed Solutions

MySQL does not provide a reason for the error; `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` returns nothing:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
-- [Type]       [Name]      [Status]
-- InnoDb
```

I have the needed database permissions.

I've double checked that the columns (and even tables) have the same collation *(character sets do not apply to INT columns)*:

```
ALTER TABLE `parents` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
ALTER TABLE `parents` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
ALTER TABLE `parents` MODIFY `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
ALTER TABLE `kids` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
ALTER TABLE `kids` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
ALTER TABLE `kids` MODIFY `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;

ALTER TABLE `kids` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `parents` (`id`);
-- Error : Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

## Discussion

I've set up many foreign keys before, but apparently something is different in this case.

The example above does not reproduce the error, which means that the schema is correct. Therefore, something besides the schema must be causing the error.

There must be a hidden setting or condition in the `parents` table or data which makes it incompatible with the `kids` table. What could it be?

## Notes

Similar questions have been asked before, but their answers did not solve the problem in this particular case.

- [MySQL Cannot Add Foreign Key Constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534977/mysql-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)
- [MySQL : ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930084/mysql-error-1215-hy000-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)
- [Cannot add foreign key constraint - MySQL ERROR 1215 (HY000)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29248057/cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-mysql-error-1215-hy000)

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem on sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7eb8e/1

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question. The example shows what the schema looks like, so that means the problem is unrelated to the schema.

Comment: Ckeck: `select count(*) from kids k left join parents p on p.id = k.parent_id where p.id is null`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Shouldnt the `LEFT JOIN` be inverted? Unless you are talking kids without parents?

Comment: @Paul Spiegel `kids` has no rows at all; it's a new table.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza that is exactly what I want - Find kids without parents. If they exist, the FK can't be created.

Comment: Troubleshooting an unreproduce-able error is challenging:  http://rextester.com/MLE20603 same as paul it works. Maybe the engine is trying to create it with an object name that already exists?  Try naming the constraint? `ALTER TABLE kids ADD CONSTRAINT KidsFKParents FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parents(id);`?

Comment: @xQbert Naming the constraint produces the same error.

Comment: Since your "Sample" isn't an exact replica of your tables... Are you SURE the types are both signed/unsigned same data type/size? and is setup as primary key?  `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` showing nothing is disconcerting.  Are you sure the alter attempt was made in the same database environment & Schema (now grasping at straws since we can't reproduce error)

Comment: @xQbert Yes, I am 100% certain that the example schema matches the real one. I copied and pasted the schema from the real one, removed the unrelated columns (non-keys), and renamed the columns/tables. This is why I'm so stumped.

Comment: Logically the syntax is correct if others can get this to work.  that leaves the issue specific to your environment.  Since we don't have the exact two tables and setup; we have to trust all of the needed requirements on size type have been met.  That leaves us with odd ball questions like: are you sure the alter is being attempted on the schema that has the tables and in the same environments and those environments do not have data.

Comment: You said these two tables are just removal of columns not needed; though we can't recreate the error.  Do you by chance already have a FK on parent_ID to a different table?  or a second column also setup as PK?  Could we see the entire table structure; or can you try and recreate in a fiddle to see if you can recreate the error using the entire structure?

Comment: If your example cant reproduce the error then isnt a good example. My suggestion start with this example and start adding thing until you reach your current structure to find out what cause the error.

Comment: "removed the unrelated columns (non-keys), and renamed the columns/tables" - Please post the exact create statement. If you don't know where the problem is, how can you know it's not there?

Comment: ha  Juan and Paul all thinking alike.

Comment: I suspect the name of the foreign key constraint is a duplicate. Try giving it an explicit name.

Comment: Time to bring the big guns, now we have @Barmar  here.

Comment: @xQbert I cannot publish the real schema, but I can test it on sqlfiddle. It does not produce an error on sqlfiddle. It was a direct copy and paste there.

Comment: @barmar we did that 29 minutes ago ;P  I had a similar thought.  GreenRaccoon23  That to me implies that it's a server setting unique to your server.  Do you have a different instance of mySQL that you could recreate tables and try?  if it works there then we know it's server specific at least; but still don't know what.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/dealing-with-mysql-error-code-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint  Is the parent table partitioned?   or is ID virtual?
 Guessing not given the create but hey.... straws again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow `NULL` for your Foreign KEY

```
CREATE TABLE `kids` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NULL, // <<== HERE 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT parent_fk FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
   REFERENCES parents(parent_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Comment: Only if there was data. there is no data.

Comment: @xQbert Well the problem cant be reproduced anyway, so at least try something ;)

Comment: This is true :P  and these types of issue you second guess everything you know even when you know its right.