# Add constraint so the column accepts only comma separated values from another column

Tags: mysql, constraints

I have these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `car_shop` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `selling_brands` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `some_col` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `cars` (
  `car_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `car_make` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`car_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The second one is populated with following:

```
+--------+----------+
| car_id | car_make |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | BMW      |
|      2 | Audi     |
|      3 | Toyota   |
+--------+----------+
```

I need to add such a constraint that column selling_brands would accept only values populated in car table (BMW, Audi, Toyota).

I imagine it that way:

```
+----+----------------+----------+
| id | selling_brands | some_col |
+----+----------------+----------+
|  1 | BMW, Audi      | shop 1   |
|  2 | Toyota         | shop 2   |
+----+----------------+----------+
```

I was trying to add constraint as follows, but it doesn't work:

```
ALTER TABLE car_shop
ADD FOREIGN KEY (selling_brands) 
REFERENCES cars(car_make)
```

I'm getting: *ERROR: (conn:24) Cannot add foreign key constraint
Error Code: 1215*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot add foreign key constraint - MySQL ERROR 1215 (HY000)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29248057/cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-mysql-error-1215-hy000)

Comment: You're telling us your second mistake, your first is trying to put comma separated values in a field.

Comment: No, your first mistake is trying to break 3NF. Don't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting comma-separated values, or any sort of lists really, into a database is almost always a bad idea. Usually, when you think you need a "list", what you really need is another table; in your case:

```
cars
- car_id
- info about the car

shops
- shop_id
- info about the shop

car_shop
- car_id
- shop_id
```

If a shop "has" more than one car, more than one row in car_shop will reference its shop_id. If a car is in more than one shop, more than one row in car_shop will have its car_id. `car_shop` could also be used to contain information such as quantity, price, etc...