# Foreign Keys Referencing multiple primary key & cannot add foreign key constraint on MySQL

Tags: mysql

This is my first time working on database, and I couldn't find a way out on this problem.
I was trying to add foreign key to one of columns in my table, but it gets

```
"ERROR 1215 : Cannot add foreign key constraint"
```

I googled this problem, but it was pretty hard to figure out what is wrong.
Here's what happened
I wanted my tables be like below

**tableA** 
└ id  - *PRIMARY KEY*
└ name 
└ password

**tableB** 
└ title 
└ no - *PRIMARY KEY*
└ and so on... (plenty of more columns here) then!!
└ unique_id - *PRIMARY KEY*
(So, tableB has multiple primary keys)

**tableC**
└ id - *References tableA (id)* & *PRIMARY KEY*
└ no - *References tableB (no)* & *PRIMARY KEY*
└ memo 
(So does tableC)

So I created columns like this, and I tried to set foreign keys in **tableC**

*id* column have gone well, but *no* column still returns error code I mentioned above, 
`Error code 1215`.

I matched a data type for both tableC's id and tableB's id.

What did I do wrong?? :(

P.S. Maybe is this with something from documentation?? (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

*However, in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.*

Comment: You matched the data type, but have you matched the display length as well?

Comment: Are you using InnoDB as the engine for all tables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint (foreign keys)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691282/error-code-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-foreign-keys)

Comment: @N.B. I'm not sure. I'll check it

Comment: @Zyga Yes. All tables are using InnoDB

Comment: When you say you have 2 columns in the same table that have PRIMARY KEY, do you intend that the primary key is a composite of both? TableB seems strange... if unique_id is "unique", then why do you need a composite primary key? Anyway... to reference a composite primary key, you must have all columns in the referencing table... not just one.

Comment: Just post the whole table structure. Do `show create table table_name;` and post the result.

Comment: I forgot to finish this question. As I discussed this problem with my partners, one of my partners misunderstood the structure of database. It should have been like this. **tableA** has another column called "unique_id", and in **tableB**, "unique_id" references "unique)id" in **tableA**. Anyway thanks for answering my  question guys. :)