# MySQL Error 150 Can't assign Genre as a foreign key from the Genre table into Album table

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-150

I don't know why the error code keeps popping up. What i'm trying to do is set the Genre column in my Album table to a foreign key that links to the Genre column in the Genre Table. But every time I try to implement Genre as a foreign key in the SQL command on Albums, I keep getting error 150 with no indication to what the error can be. As the field information is identical in both tables.

***Code behind my Albums table***

```
CREATE TABLE `Albums` (  
`Album_id` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`Album_Name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,  
`Number_Of_Tracks` int(11) NOT NULL,    
`Genre` varchar(32) NOT NULL,  
`Track_id` int(6) NOT NULL,  
`Artist_id` int(6) NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY  (`Album_id`),  
KEY `Track_id` (`Track_id`),  
KEY `Artist_id` (`Artist_id`),  CONSTRAINT `Albums_ibfk_1` 
FOREIGN KEY (`Track_id`) REFERENCES `Tracks` (`Track_id`),  CONSTRAINT `Albums_ibfk_2`     
FOREIGN KEY (`Artist_id`) REFERENCES `Artist` (`Artist_id`)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB 
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

***Code behind my Genre table***

```
CREATE TABLE `Genre` (  
`Genre_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
`Genre` varchar(32) NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY  (`Genre_id`)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

***Code i'm using on SQL to try and make Genre in Albums a Foreign key***

```
ALTER TABLE Albums
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`Genre`)
REFERENCES Genre (`Genre`)
```

Can anyone help me understand what's going wrong?

Comment: InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). **Please DO READ THE DOCUMENTATION**. Furthermore, I recommend to use an int(11) column in the `albums` table and use the existing numeric key as the reference (instead of the character representation of the genre)

Comment: So because genre in the genre table isn't the 1st column that's why it's coming up with the error?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691282/error-code-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-foreign-keys

Comment: But everything should be working, i've ensured the field and their data match from both tables. My only conclusion it that it's because it's not the primary key, so would I have to instead make a compound key out of both Genre_id and Genre itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put:

```
`Genre` int(11) NOT NULL,
```

and

```
KEY `Genre` (`Genre`),
```

in Albums.
Then the following works:

```
ALTER TABLE Albums
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`Genre`)
REFERENCES Genre (`Genre_id`);
```

The reasons of not working are:

1. Type mismatch
2. Genre is not a key in Albums
3. You are not referencing the primary key of Genres

Look here for expanded clarifications:

[Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint (foreign keys)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691282/error-code-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-foreign-keys)

Comment: I've tried the following to no success.     ALTER TABLE tbl_Albums
MODIFY COLUMN`Genre` int(11) NOT NULL,
ADD KEY `Genre` (`Genre`),
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`Genre`),
REFERENCES tbl_Genre (`Genre_id`)

Comment: First make ALTER TABLE tbl_Albums MODIFY COLUMN Genre int(11) NOT NULL, ADD KEY Genre (Genre); then run ALTER TABLE Albums
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`Genre`) REFERENCES Genre (`Genre_id`);

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the primary key field in Genre (Genre.Genre_id) as the foreign key.  You can't use Genre.Genre.

"A FOREIGN KEY in one table points to a PRIMARY KEY in another table."

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp