# MySQL Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint (the datatypes of the two columns match)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am trying to create a foreign key constraint to the existing table only to receive `Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint`. Below I include `SHOW CREATE TABLE observation_log_status;`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE observation_log;` outputs and the foreign key constraint statement that fails. I have checked (according to the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691282/error-code-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-foreign-keys)) that the datatypes of the two columns are the same (they are) and if the two columns were signed or unsigned (according to the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028214/add-foreign-key-to-existing-table)) (they are neither), but the error remains the same. I am using MySQL 5.7.17.

Thanks,
Aina.

EDIT: this is not a duplicate, but I am obliged now to explain how it is different. In the question that is meant to be the duplicate the OP didn't have the same datatype for the two columns, I do, as shown by my SHOW CREATE TABLE statements outputs.

*********************************SOLUTION**************************************

ANOTHER EDIT: As P.Salmon suggested the problem was indeed the ENGINE.
I solved it by running `ALTER TABLE observation_log ENGINE = InnoDB;`.
Then the `ALTER TABLE observation_log_status ADD CONSTRAINT observation_log_fk FOREIGN KEY (aat_id) REFERENCES observation_log(aat_id);` statement worked fine.

*********************************SOLUTION**************************************

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE observation_log;
observation_log, CREATE TABLE `observation_log` (
`aat_id` decimal(14,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `utdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `session` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  ...,
  `aaoprgid` char(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`aat_id`),
  KEY `obs_object` (`object`),
  KEY `obs_utdate` (`utdate`),
  KEY `obs_ra_dec` (`raj2000_int`,`decj2000_int`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

SHOW CREATE TABLE observation_log_status;
observation_log_status, CREATE TABLE `observation_log_status` (
  `observation_log_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `aat_id` decimal(14,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `data_needs_processing_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `data_file_transfer_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `megatable_update_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `data_file_search_attempt_count` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `data_file_trasnfer_attempt_count` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `megatable_update_attempt_count` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `data_file_transfer_timer` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `row_insert_time` datetime(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`observation_log_status_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The statement the generates the error:

```
ALTER TABLE observation_log_status ADD CONSTRAINT observation_log_fk FOREIGN KEY (aat_id) REFERENCES observation_log(aat_id);
```

Comment: Do either of these tables have data in them?  If you add a foreign key to `observation_log_status` I believe that every foreign key in that table must point to a primary key in `observation_log`.

Comment: Hi Tim, the `observation_log_status` doesn't have any other foreign keys. And yes, the `observation_log` table have a lot of rows of data, the `observation_log_status` table is completely new, no rows have been added yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint (foreign keys)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691282/error-code-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-foreign-keys)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, Alexander, I have read and tested that suggestion (and linked it in my question). Thanks, Aina.

Comment: Works fine if the engine is the same.

Comment: P.Salmon, it worked! Would you like to put your comment as an answer so I can accept it? `ALTER TABLE observation_log ENGINE = InnoDB;' solved everything!

Answer (score 0):

***aat_id` decimal(14,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'***

Try removing the default value. Foreign keys cannot have default value. Only those value present in the primary key can be accepted by foreign key

Comment: Hi Aashi, I have just tried that and the error is still the same. Just to double-check I followed your advice correctly:
    `DROP TABLE observation_log_status;
    CREATE TABLE observation_log_status(
    observation_log_status_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    aat_id DECIMAL(14,0) NOT NULL,
    row_insert_time DATETIME(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
);
   ALTER TABLE observation_log_status ADD CONSTRAINT observation_log_fk FOREIGN KEY (aat_id) REFERENCES observation_log(aat_id);`

Comment: [link](https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/04/06/dealing-mysql-error-code-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint/) try this link